Memory leak that GC doesn't fix regarding .Net Entity Framework version 8 (C# console app .Net8.02 )
For most things I write, I usually don't care about memory usage, however, I have a console app written in .Net8.02 using EF8, that leaks 2MB every time an EF transaction is called. I've tried every conceivable arrangement of GC (garbage collector) trying to force .Net to release memory between calls, but the leak persists.  I've also put code snippets in all sorts of places to track memory usage and it all comes back to EF.  2MB may not seem like much, but, daily, this program reads in about 5,000 log files (or more) and the program crashes the machine (VM or real) - I wrote a memory monitor with GC to look at available memory, then stop processing and wait until it goes back down (it never does!).
Anyway, this is the area where the problem lies (LogFileProcessor.cs).
If anyone has any ideas on how to release memory that EF gobbles up, I'd greatly appreciate it (before I go back and use ADO.Net Core (which does not have the same issue - go figure)
 public partial class LogFileProcessor(LogDbContext dbContext, ILogger<LogFileProcessor> logger)
 {
     private readonly LogDbContext _dbContext = dbContext;
     private readonly ILogger<LogFileProcessor> _logger = logger;

     private List<LogEntry> _logEntries = new List<LogEntry>();
     private string[] _lines = [];

     public async Task<bool> ProcessLogFileAsync(string filePath)
     {
         bool result = false;

         if (!File.Exists(filePath))
         {
             _logger.LogError("File not found: {filePath}", filePath);
             return result;
         }

         string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

         if (await LogAlreadyProcessedAsync(fileName))
         {
             _logger.LogInformation("Log file already processed: {fileName}", fileName);
             return result;
         }

         string fileNameNoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
         DateTime fileDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath);
         string fileHash = ProgramBase.ComputeSha256Hash(filePath);
         int logFileId = ExtractLogFileId(fileNameNoExt);
         string fileType = ExtractFileType(fileNameNoExt);

         using var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
         try
         {
             var parsedLog = new ParsedLog
             {
                 FileName = fileName,
                 LogType = fileType,
                 LogFileId = logFileId,
                 DateParsed = DateTime.UtcNow,
                 FileDate = fileDate,
                 FileHash = fileHash
             };

             await _dbContext.ParsedLogs.AddAsync(parsedLog);
             await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

             int parsedLogId = parsedLog.Id; //retrieve new Id (identity) from ParsedLogs table

             //_lines = await File.ReadLinesAsync(filePath).ToArray();   //not really needed, but if user sets log file size really large, this is better for resources
             _lines = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(filePath);
             int lineNum = 0;
             foreach (var line in _lines)
             {
                 var entry = ParseLine(line, parsedLogId, lineNum);
                 if (entry != null)
                 {
                     _logEntries.Add(entry);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     throw new Exception($"Unable to parse or convert line {lineNum}");
                 }
                 lineNum += 1;
             }

             await _dbContext.LogEntries.AddRangeAsync(_logEntries);
             await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

             await transaction.CommitAsync();
             _logger.LogInformation("Log file: {fileName} processed and data committed to the database.", fileName);
             await transaction.DisposeAsync();
             result = true;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             await transaction.RollbackAsync();
             _logger.LogError("Error processing log file: {fileName} {ex.Message}", fileName, ex.Message);
             await transaction.DisposeAsync();
             result = false;
         }
         finally
         {
             _logEntries.Clear();
             _lines = [];

             // Force garbage collection - naturally, this doesn't work, UGH!
             GC.Collect();
             GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
             GC.Collect();
         }
         return result;
     }



     private async Task<bool> LogAlreadyProcessedAsync(string fileName)
     {
         return await _dbContext.ParsedLogs.AsNoTracking().AnyAsync(l => l.FileName == fileName);
     }

     private static string ExtractFileType(string fileNameNoExt)
     {
         var match = FileTypeRegex().Match(fileNameNoExt);
         return match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : "unknown";
     }

     private static int ExtractLogFileId(string fileNameNoExt)
     {
         var match = FileIdRegex().Match(fileNameNoExt);
         return match.Success ? int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) : 0;
     }


     private static LogEntry? ParseLine(string line, int parsedLogId, int lineNum)
     {
         var parts = line.Split("->", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
         if (parts.Length < 2) return null;

         var dateTimePart = parts[0].Trim();
         string ipPart = string.Empty;
         string statusAndRestPart;

         // Check if the IP address is present
         if (parts.Length == 3)
         {
             ipPart = parts[1].Trim();
             statusAndRestPart = parts[2].Trim();
         }
         else
         {
             // Assume the IP address is missing and adjust accordingly
             statusAndRestPart = parts[1].Trim();
         }

         var statusPart = statusAndRestPart.Split(':', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)[0];
         var actionDetailsPart = ActionDetailsRegex().Match(statusAndRestPart);

         string action = actionDetailsPart.Groups[1].Value.Trim();
         string details = actionDetailsPart.Groups.Count > 2 ? actionDetailsPart.Groups[2].Value.Trim() : string.Empty;

         return new LogEntry
         {
             ParsedLogId = parsedLogId,
             LineNum = lineNum,
             EntryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimePart, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
             IPaddress = ipPart,
             Status = statusPart,
             Action = action,
             Details = details
         };
     }

     // generates all regexes at compile time
     [GeneratedRegex(@"^(.*?)_\d+$")]
     private static partial Regex FileTypeRegex();

     [GeneratedRegex(@"_([0-9]+)$")]
     private static partial Regex FileIdRegex();

     [GeneratedRegex(@"Action=\[(.*?)\](?:, Details=\[(.*?)\])?", RegexOptions.Compiled)]
     private static partial Regex ActionDetailsRegex();
 }

The program.cs file:
    namespace LogParserApp;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

internal partial class Program : ProgramBase
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settings = ParseArguments(args);

        if (!settings.TryGetValue("filetype", out List<string>? value) || value.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please specify at least one filetype using '-filetype \"smtp, pop3\"'.");
            return;
        }

        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        // Access the configuration and the LogFileProcessor service
        var config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        string? folderPath = settings.TryGetValue("folderpath", out List<string>? value1) && value1.Count > 0 ? value1[0]
                              : config["LogFileSettings:FolderPath"];

        string? archivePath = settings.TryGetValue("archivepath", out List<string>? value2) && value2.Count > 0 ? value2[0]
                              : config["LogFileSettings:ArchivePath"];

        var logFileProcessor = host.Services.GetRequiredService<LogFileProcessor>();

        string postProcess = settings.TryGetValue("postprocess", out List<string>? value3) && value3.Count > 0 ? value3[0].ToLower() : "keep";


        foreach (var fileType in value)
        {
            var logFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath ?? "C:\\logs", $"{fileType}_*.txt")
                .Select(file => new
                {
                    FileName = file,
                    OrderKey = int.Parse(OrderKeyRegex().Match(Path.GetFileName(file)).Groups[1].Value)
                })
                .OrderBy(f => f.OrderKey)
                .Select(f => f.FileName);

            //long memOffset = GC.GetTotalMemory(forceFullCollection: true); //for tracking memory

            foreach (var file in logFiles)
            {
                // EnsureAvailableMemory(); //to keep program from crashing, no joy

                //long startMem = GC.GetTotalMemory(forceFullCollection: true);  //for tracking memory

                Console.WriteLine($"Processing file: {file}");
                var processSuccess = (await logFileProcessor.ProcessLogFileAsync(file));

                if (processSuccess)
                {
                    switch (postProcess)
                    {
                        case "archive":
                            string targetPath = Path.Combine(archivePath ?? "C:\\logs\\archive", Path.GetFileName(file));
                            File.Move(file, targetPath);
                            Console.WriteLine($"Archived file to: {targetPath}");
                            break;
                        case "delete":
                            File.Delete(file);
                            Console.WriteLine($"Deleted file: {file}");
                            break;
                        case "keep":
                            // Nothing to do, may add something later to keep, but rename, or what-have-you
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Processing failed for file: {file}, skipping post-processing steps.");
                }

                GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

                //long endMem = GC.GetTotalMemory(forceFullCollection: true);  //for tracking memory
                //Console.WriteLine($"Memory Utilized: {(endMem - startMem) / 1048576M:N2} MB");  //for tracking memory
                //Console.WriteLine($"Running Memory: {(endMem - memOffset) / 1048576M:N2} MB");  //for tracking memory

            }
        }

        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddDbContext<LogDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddScoped<LogFileProcessor>();
            services.AddLogging(); 

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(hostContext.Configuration);
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging => {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogLevel.Warning);
        });


    // generates a regex at compile time
    [GeneratedRegex(@"^.*?_(\d+)\.txt$")]
    private static partial Regex OrderKeyRegex();


    // this doesn't help - garbage collection never actually occurs, so it stays at 1GB & tries again indefinitely
    public static void EnsureAvailableMemory()
    {
        const long maxAllowedMemory = 1_073_741_824; // Set threshold to 1 GB

        while (true)
        {
            long memoryUsed = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
            Console.WriteLine($"Memory used: {memoryUsed} bytes");

            if (memoryUsed < maxAllowedMemory)
            {
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Memory usage is too high, forcing garbage collection.");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Console.WriteLine("Garbage collection complete, pausing for a few seconds...");
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // Wait 5 seconds before checking again
        }
    }

}

Note the last method (I've tried various things with the GC, but no joy).
The entities (probably won't help, but here they are)
public class ParsedLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LogType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int LogFileId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateParsed { get; set; }
    public DateTime FileDate { get; set; }
    public string? FileHash { get; set; }  // SHA-256 hash of the file
}

public class LogEntry
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int ParsedLogId { get; set; }
    public int LineNum { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public string IPaddress { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Status { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Action { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Details { get; set; } = string.Empty;

}


public class LogDbContext(DbContextOptions<LogDbContext> options) : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ParsedLog> ParsedLogs { get; set; }
}

I plan on refactoring for obvious speed improvements (pre-hashing the files, using spans, bulkinsert, etc), but the memory problem is pretty severe when doing thousands of files.
Here is some output to demonstrate the memory going up to 1GB 1-2MB at a time
    PS D:\Projects\LogParserApp> dotnet run -filetype "smtp" -postprocess "archive"

Processing file: D:\EmailLogs\smtp_0.txt
info: LogParserApp.LogFileProcessor[0]
      Log file: smtp_0.txt processed and data committed to the database.
Archived file to: D:\EmailLogs\ArchivedLogs\smtp_0.txt
Memory Utilized: 12.27 MB
Running Memory: 12.49 MB
Processing file: D:\EmailLogs\smtp_1.txt
info: LogParserApp.LogFileProcessor[0]
      Log file: smtp_1.txt processed and data committed to the database.
Archived file to: D:\EmailLogs\ArchivedLogs\smtp_1.txt
Memory Utilized: 2.78 MB
Running Memory: 15.27 MB
Processing file: D:\EmailLogs\smtp_2.txt
info: LogParserApp.LogFileProcessor[0]
      Log file: smtp_2.txt processed and data committed to the database.
Archived file to: D:\EmailLogs\ArchivedLogs\smtp_2.txt
Memory Utilized: 2.48 MB
Running Memory: 17.74 MB
Processing file: D:\EmailLogs\smtp_3.txt
info: LogParserApp.LogFileProcessor[0]
      Log file: smtp_3.txt processed and data committed to the database.
Archived file to: D:\EmailLogs\ArchivedLogs\smtp_3.txt
Memory Utilized: 3.28 MB
Running Memory: 21.03 MB
Processing file: D:\EmailLogs\smtp_4.txt
info: LogParserApp.LogFileProcessor[0]
      Log file: smtp_4.txt processed and data committed to the database.
Archived file to: D:\EmailLogs\ArchivedLogs\smtp_4.txt
Memory Utilized: 2.28 MB
Running Memory: 23.31 MB
Processing file: D:\EmailLogs\smtp_5.txt
info: LogParserApp.LogFileProcessor[0]
      Log file: smtp_5.txt processed and data committed to the database.
Archived file to: D:\EmailLogs\ArchivedLogs\smtp_5.txt
Memory Utilized: 2.55 MB
Running Memory: 25.86 MB
...
...
...
Processing file: D:\EmailLogs\smtp_370.txt
info: LogParserApp.LogFileProcessor[0]
      Log file: smtp_370.txt processed and data committed to the database.
Archived file to: D:\EmailLogs\ArchivedLogs\smtp_370.txt
Memory Utilized: 2.36 MB
Running Memory: 999.33 MB
Processing file: D:\EmailLogs\smtp_371.txt
info: LogParserApp.LogFileProcessor[0]
      Log file: smtp_371.txt processed and data committed to the database.
Archived file to: D:\EmailLogs\ArchivedLogs\smtp_371.txt
Memory Utilized: 2.59 MB
Running Memory: 1,001.92 MB
Processing file: D:\EmailLogs\smtp_372.txt
info: LogParserApp.LogFileProcessor[0]
      Log file: smtp_372.txt processed and data committed to the database.
Archived file to: D:\EmailLogs\ArchivedLogs\smtp_372.txt
Memory Utilized: 2.24 MB
Running Memory: 1,004.16 MB

That's for 373 files - imagine 10 thousand files. :)

Adding entities to the DbContext will add them to the tracking cache. I would use a DbContextFactory dependency rather than a single scoped DbContext so each iteration to insert logs etc. a fresh DbContext instance is created and disposed automatically. Alternatively you could detach all entities after adding to remove them from the tracking cache so the references can be cleaned up appropriately.

How do you know that memory "leaks"? I don't think it's a leak. Most probably it's an intended feature of Entity Framework to track entities in the DbContext.

Don't touch GC in your code. Instead of finding the root cause and solving the problem, you are creating another problem. GC is meant to work automatically.

One thing to do is remove the file.Exists() check. Instead, add the log message and return false as part of a FileNotFoundException exception handler. This will save you disk I/O on average. Additionally, change File.ReadAllLinesAsync() to just File.ReadLinesAsync() (and await the loop)

Use a memory profiler such as ANTS or dotMemory to find out what objects are building up. I'm going to hazard a guess that it might actually be the Regex which is generating dyanmic modules: RegexOptions.Compiled makes no sense on GeneratedRegex and might actually be counter-productive. But I agree, you definitely shouldn't be caching DbContext long-term.

I would argue that this answer and comments to it can be useful.

The simplest way to handle this is to create a service scope per file;
foreach (var file in logFiles)
{
    using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
    var logFileProcessor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LogFileProcessor>();
...

All your scoped services will be disposed when the scope is disposed.

This immediately worked. Makes perfect sense now that I think about it more (didn't know you could do this) - I ran w/changes - memory usage is now flat.

It looks like you're using the same instance of LogFileProcessor (and by extension, the same context) for each log file. Unless you tell it otherwise, any entities added to the context will continue to be tracked, so the more files processed the more entities it will be tracking, leading to higher memory usage.
You could try clearing the context after each file is successfully processed. Just call _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear() at the end of your ProcessLogFileAsync method.
Also, be wary of directly calling GC.Collect within your code unless you really really really know what you're doing.

One consideration is this line:
_lines = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(filePath);

... which loads the entire file into memory all at once.
We can change this to only ever need one line from a file in memory at a time by removing just two lines and changing three others.
To accomplish this, first remove the private string[] _lines = []; declaration at the beginning of the class, and the corresponding _lines = []; at the end of the finally — you don't need them, and yay for simpler code.
We then rewrite these three lines:
_lines = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(filePath);
int lineNum = 0;
foreach (var line in _lines)

like so:
int lineNum = 0;
await foreach (var line in File.ReadLinesAsync(filePath))

Nothing else changes. Note it's just ReadLinesAsync(), with no All.

While I'm here, you can also save waiting on disk I/O on average once per file by removing this code:
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    _logger.LogError("File not found: {filePath}", filePath);
    return result;
}

Really: just delete it. Let the code try to open the file whether it exists or not.
Instead add this exception handler above the catch (Exception ex) line, so you have two exception handlers on the same try:
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    _logger.LogError("File not found: {filePath}", filePath);
    return false;
}

If the file does not exist and you try to open it, you have the exact same amount of disk I/O as if you ran the .Exists() check: it's one round-trip out to the file system either way. What you lose is the cost of unwinding the stack to create the exception handler object, which is why for the general case we avoid using exceptions like this for flow control. But if the file does exist, you saved the .Exists() check entirely... for potentially "5,000 log files (or more)". Given disk I/O is about the slowest thing you can do in a computer (much slower even than unwinding the call stack for an exception handler!), this can add up, and skipping the manual Exists() check in favor an exception handler is almost always the right option if you want to open the file anyway.
This trick is especially useful for your code as the .Exists() check was not asynchronous. And as this seems likely to be I/O bound rather than CPU bound, shifting some potential load from I/O to CPU/Memory for the stack unwind could also be a big win for creating spaces where the asynchronous code can actually task switch to get other work done.
Additionally, because the file system is volatile, you're really supposed have an exception handler for this anyway — the .Exists() check on it's own is not enough, and so removing it to rely only the exception actually saves code overall. In fact, you also ought to have handlers for DirectoryNotFoundException, SecurityException, IOException, UnauthorizedAccessException and all the other things from the Exceptions section of the docs that could cause a file to not read other than whether it exists or not, but falling back to the base Exception type is good enough for most situations.

Finally, if it were me, I might let the method to process one file stay synchronous, but then make sure I had the ability to kick off processing each of the files asynchronously, where I'm certain it will NOT wait for one file to finish before starting the next. That is, let the asynchronous work happen at the file level instead of the individual operation level.
The high level view is something like this, where ProcessOneFile() could even be synchronous:
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var filePath in files)
{
    // Do NOT await here
    tasks.Add(Task.Run( f => ProcessOneFile(filePath) );
}
// await them all at once here instead
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Given the quantity of files you have, I might further want to batch these into groups of, say, 50, but this is general idea.
But even then, I feel like this code is likely to be I/O bound rather than CPU bound, such that all the asynchronous work may be making things worse, rather than better... that you may be better off ensuring you're not causing drive trashing.

I'm looking into this part today (scoping the service by file was the first part), but have a question: doesn't reading a file, line by line, hold it open & lock it?

@MC9000 It can hold it open, but only until you finish with the file, and the I/O for actually reading the file is the bulk of the time... the processing part is generally almost instant. And since it's just for read it doesn't have to be an exclusive lock. There are exceptions, but you will generally do MUCH better going line-by-line.

Thanks again - I like your last suggestion (I did something similar years ago reading crypto prices off of a few exchanges in parallel before C# made it a lot easier).
I did move all the file system related stuff out of the transaction block (a separate try-catch block for each, but not nested)
